# Access other component refs from within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm looking for a way for two components to talk to each other. I simply want it so that when `<InputCheckboxAll/>` is checked or unchecked it will checked or unchecked all `<InputCheckbox/>` components.

```
var InputCheckboxAll = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type='checkbox' {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
})

var InputCheckbox = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type='checkbox' {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
})

<InputCheckboxAll ref='masterCheckbox'/>
<InputCheckbox masterRef='masterCheckbox'/>
<InputCheckbox masterRef='masterCheckbox'/>
<InputCheckbox masterRef='masterCheckbox'/>
```

How from within the `<InputCheckboxAll>` component can I select all refs with `masterCheckbox` on the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass handler to InputCheckboxAll and state to InputCheckbox.

```
    var InputCheckboxAll = React.createClass({
        handleChange: function(event) {
            this.props.handleChange(event);
        },
      render: function () {
        return (
          <input type='checkbox' {...this.props} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        )
      }
    })

    var InputCheckbox = React.createClass({
      render: function () {
            var checkedValue = this.props.allChecked ? true : this.state.checked;
        return (
          <input checked={checkedValue} type='checkbox' {...this.props}/>
        )
      }
    })

    var CheckMaster = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() { return {allChecked: false}; },
        handleChange: function(event) {
            this.setState({allChecked: event.target.value});
        },
        render: function () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <InputCheckboxAll handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <InputCheckbox allChecked={this.state.allChecked}/>
                    <InputCheckbox allChecked={this.state.allChecked}/>
                    <InputCheckbox allChecked={this.state.allChecked}/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this, it's great! One issue is that `<InputCheckbox>` needs `getInitialState` where `checked`  is false, however this makes it uncheckable on it's own.

Comment: I checked the value of `getInitialState` `checked` to `this.props.checked` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Let's say all three `<InputCheckbox>` are checked how can I change the value of `<InputCheckboxAll>` to checked?

Comment: You could pass a checked handler to InputCheckbox and have state for each id (add id for each) and add an allInputChecked and pass to InputCheckedAll.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean by "have state for each id"?

Comment: I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641541/react-input-checkbox-select-all-component