# React - dynamically create select all checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-redux

There has been a number of questions on React checkboxes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644711/modularize-and-abstract-react-component-functionality) is pretty good, and it helps to modularize the idea of select-all checkboxes in React.

Now, I have a problem. I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
  regionOne: {
    subareaOne,
    subareaTwo,
    subareaThree,
    subareaFour
  },
  regionTwo: {
    subareaFive,
    subareaSix
  }
}
```

Here, each region is mapped to an arbitrary number of sub areas, which I do not know beforehand.

I want to create checkboxes such that each region and each subarea has a checkbox, and each region's checkbox acts as a select-all/de-select all for all the subareas it is mapped to. That is, something like this:

[image]

[image]

So, when you click on the checkbox for `regionOne`, the checkboxes for `subareaOne`, `subareaTwo`, `subareaThree` and `subareaFour` should all be checked as well, but not those in `regionTwo`.

I think I can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644711/modularize-and-abstract-react-component-functionality), but its `getInitialState` function assumes that you know how many children checkboxes there are.

Any idea on how to do this in an elegant method? I am now considering initialising the checkboxes dynamically using mapping, but I am not sure...VanillaJS would have been much simpler >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually went ahead and implemented it anyway. There are two components involved, a parent `CheckboxGroup` component, and a child `StatelessCheckbox` component.

Here is the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { StatelessCheckbox } from './StatelessCheckbox';

export class CheckboxGroup extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: false,
            boxes: {},
            disabled: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { boxes, boxId, disabled } = this.props;
        let boxesState = {};
        boxes.map(box => {
            boxesState[box[boxId]] = false;
        });
        this.setState({ checked: false, boxes: boxesState, disabled: disabled });
    }

    handleSelectAll(event) {
        const isChecked = event.target.checked;

        let boxesState = {};
        Object.keys(this.state.boxes).map(box => {
            boxesState[box] = isChecked;
        });
        this.setState({ checked: isChecked, boxes: boxesState });
    }

    handleSelect(event) {
        const isChecked = event.target.checked;
        const boxId = event.target.value;

        let newBoxes = {};
        Object.assign(newBoxes, this.state.boxes);
        newBoxes[boxId] = isChecked;

        // Check parent checkbox if all children boxes are checked
        const checkedBoxes = Object.keys(newBoxes).filter((box) => {
            return newBoxes[box] === true;
        });
        const parentIsChecked = (checkedBoxes.length === Object.keys(newBoxes).length);

        this.setState({ checked: parentIsChecked, boxes: newBoxes });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            passDataToParent=(() => { return false; }),
            groupClassName='',
            headClassName='',
            headName='',
            headBoxClass='',
            headLabelClass='',
            headLabelText='',
            bodyClassName='',
            bodyName='',
            bodyBoxClass='',
            bodyLabelClass='',
            boxes,
            boxId,
            boxLabel
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className={ groupClassName }>
                    <div className={ headClassName }>
                        <StatelessCheckbox name={ headName } className={ headBoxClass }
                                           labelClass={ headLabelClass } labelText={ headLabelText }
                                           checked={ this.state.checked } value={ headName }
                                           passedOnChange={ (e) => { this.handleSelectAll(e); } } />
                    </div>
                    <div className={`row ${ bodyClassName }`}>
                        { boxes.map(box => (
                            <div key={ box[boxId] }>
                                <StatelessCheckbox name={ bodyName } className={ bodyBoxClass }
                                                   labelClass={ bodyLabelClass } labelText={ box[boxLabel] }
                                                   checked={ this.state.boxes[box[boxId]] } value={ box[boxId] }
                                                   passedOnChange={ (e) => { this.handleSelect(e); } } />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the child component:

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * Implements a React checkbox as a stateless component.
 */
export class StatelessCheckbox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            passedOnChange=(() => { return false; }),
            className='',
            name='',
            labelClass='',
            labelText='',
            value='',
            checked=false,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <label className={`for-checkbox ${ className }`} tabIndex="0">
                <input onChange={(e) => passedOnChange(e) }
                       checked={ checked } type="checkbox"
                       name={ name } value={ value } />
                <span className={`label ${ labelClass }`}>{ labelText }</span>
            </label>
        );
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- the child component is a stateless component in this case, used purely for rendering
- the parent component (`CheckboxGroup`) maintains the state for all the child components as well so there is still a **single source of truth** as per [React philosophy](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles)
- `boxes` in properties is a list of the children checkboxes in each parent `CheckboxGroup`, and `boxes` in the parent state holds the state for each child checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
onSelect(id) {
    let allElms = Object.assign({}, retriveElmentsSomehow());
    let elm = findTheElm(id, allElms);
    updateSelected(elm, !elm.selected);
    // Then update state with new allElms
}

updateSelected(elm, selectedOrNot) {
    elm.selected = selectedOrNot;
    if (elm.children) {
        elm.children.foreach(c => onSelect(c, selectedOrNot));
    }
}
```

Where elements are in state or redux store.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this only works in a one-way fashion right? For example, if you check all the children checkboxes, the parent checkbox will not be checked by default.