# Handle mulitple checkboxes in React

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

[UPDATE] Add Codesand: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-cherry-lf9po?file=/src/component/Assign.jsx

In my class project, I want to have checkbox interface like this:

[image]

When I click the top checkbox(Assign checkbox), all checkboxes below are checked. Otherwise, unclick the top checkbox, all below are unchecked

[image]

My approach is to create an array of checked state:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(
    new Array(4).fill(false)
  );
```

Next, handle top checkbox `onChange` event. I will update all of `isChecked` elements to checked state of the top one

```
const assign = () => {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox  onChange={(event)=> {
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          isChecked[i] = event.currentTarget.checked
        setIsChecked(isChecked)
      }
        }/>} 
      label={<span style={{ fontSize: '0.89rem' }}>
        Assign</span>} />
    )
  }
```

Below checked states are updated based on the `isChecked[]` array

```
const miniAssign = (index) => {
    return (
      <Checkbox {...label} checked={isChecked[index]}/>
    )
  }
```

This leads to a problem. When I click the top checkbox, none of the below are checked. Please tell me what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: can u create a project in code sanbox and share the link

Comment: you can find a lot of examples and same questions in StackOverflow... have you tried to search your question? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641541/react-input-checkbox-select-all-component?rq=1`

Comment: My codesand: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-cherry-lf9po?file=/src/component/Assign.jsx

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh Yes, I've tried to search in stackoverflow but not my expectation. Can you recommend some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const assign = () => {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Assign
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(event) =>
              setIsChecked(new Array(4).fill(event.currentTarget.checked))
            }
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  };

  const belowAssign = (i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked[i]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setIsChecked([
              ...isChecked.slice(0, i),
              e.target.checked,
              ...isChecked.slice(i + 1)
            ])
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {assign()}
      {isChecked.map((_, i) => belowAssign(i))}
    </div>
  );
```