# how to toggle all checkbox by clicking header checkbox react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

is there anyone to help that how can i implement functionality in toggleCheckboxes() to select all checkboxes. In my code there is a map method. it controls the number of checkbox input's. In table Data, every checkbox type input is shown after mapping an item from manageOrder. i tried with using useState, setAttribute but can't to solve this problem.

````
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Container, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './ManageAllOrder.css';

const ManageAllOrder = () => {
    const [manageOrder, setManageOrder] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://ghostly-blood-77078.herokuapp.com/orders')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setManageOrder(data))
    }, [])
    //change status after click
    const changeStatus= (e) => {
        e.target.innerText = 'active'
    }
    //toggle checkbox
    const rowCheckbox = useRef('')
    const toggleCheckboxes = () => {
        


    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <div>
                <h3 className='my-4' style={{color: '#34495E'}}>Order Management</h3>
                <div>
                {!manageOrder.length ? 
                      <Spinner animation="grow" variant="warning" /> :

                    //table to show data
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead className='table-warning'>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input id='header-checkbox' type='checkbox' onClick={toggleCheckboxes()} /></th>
                                <th>OrderID</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Customer</th>
                                <th>Order</th>
                                <th>Place</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                    {manageOrder.map(order =>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p><input type='checkbox' ref={rowCheckbox}/></p></td>
                                <td><p>{order._id}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.date}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.displayName}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.name}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.place}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.amount}</p></td>
                                <td><p onClick={(e) => changeStatus(e)}>pending...</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default ManageAllOrder;```


[i want to toggle all checkboxes after clicking the checkbox top left corner, i tried a few ways to implement that but i can't because of map method. ][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfbSJ.png
````

Comment: I Guess that you are trying to implement the "select all" option(?). 
It is addressed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641541/react-input-checkbox-select-all-component?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a **useState** hook to set checked to true/false, then use the input prop **checked** and set it with the state like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Container, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './ManageAllOrder.css';

const ManageAllOrder = () => {
    const [manageOrder, setManageOrder] = useState([]);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://ghostly-blood-77078.herokuapp.com/orders')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setManageOrder(data))
    }, [])
    //change status after click
    const changeStatus= (e) => {
        e.target.innerText = 'active'
    }
    //toggle checkbox
    const rowCheckbox = useRef('')
    const toggleCheckboxes = () => {
        setChecked(prevState => !prevState)
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <div>
                <h3 className='my-4' style={{color: '#34495E'}}>Order Management</h3>
                <div>
                {!manageOrder.length ? 
                      <Spinner animation="grow" variant="warning" /> :

                    //table to show data
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead className='table-warning'>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input id='header-checkbox' type='checkbox' onClick={toggleCheckboxes} /></th>
                                <th>OrderID</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Customer</th>
                                <th>Order</th>
                                <th>Place</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                    {manageOrder.map(order =>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p><input type='checkbox' ref={rowCheckbox} checked={checked}/></p></td>
                                <td><p>{order._id}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.date}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.displayName}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.name}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.place}</p></td>
                                <td><p>{order.amount}</p></td>
                                <td><p onClick={(e) => changeStatus(e)}>pending...</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default ManageAllOrder;
```

Comment: if you don't worry i would like to share a link to you to find out this problem more effectively, that is:  "https://zealous-bhaskara-09c56b.netlify.app/manage-all-order"  .Please help me with paste this link to your browser. In that page i want click header checkbox and want to select all below all checkboxes.

Comment: I see it, can you please explain what is missing in the solution I gave you?

Comment: i tried your solution when you gave this. but it doesn't work. i don't know why its not working.

Comment: Do you get some kind of an error, can you share perhaps a codesandbox?

Comment: i am extremely sorry your code is true and 100% working. i was made a mistake when you gave me this solution. that was totally my fault. my problem has been solved. thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad I could help.

Comment: i have just one more question to you, can i ask?

Comment: Please go ahead

Comment: i uploaded an image using FormData to a mongodb collection named "products" collection and saved to the mongodb as base64 string. then in the front-end i fetched this image to another component from that collection. now it is a b64 image string and now i want to send this image (or after convert this string to a file) to the other collection named "order" collection of mongodb. so how can i do that?

Comment: It is hard to help with such a question in comments? how about you write a new question for it?

Comment: Normally it shows me an error which is "payload to large". for this error i installed body-perser in the backend(node js) and followed stack-overflow guideline. i wan't able to solve this error. i tried many way to send this image string (or after converting string to file ) to the backend. my final talk is how can i send this image string or after convert this string to a file to the mongodb collection so that i can show image in the front-end after fetching.

Comment: if you don't mind here is my code: https://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=lw3EdufbU7

Answer (score 0):

First of all I couldn’t see where are you setting the checkbox value in state. So what you can do is set checked firewood for each entry from the data fetched and then update that field accordingly and once you click on check all checkboxes then iterate the list marking all of them as true also you should populate that value back to your checkboxes(binding the data). Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: if you don't mind this is my link: "https://zealous-bhaskara-09c56b.netlify.app/manage-all-order".after clicking header checkbox i want to select all below checkboxes, how can i do that?